# How to integrate the Identity Server 4 (authorization code flow - PKCE) in a project using Vue.js and ASP.Net Core Web Api?

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-core-webapi, identityserver4, pkce

I' am looking for an example how to integrate the Identity Server 4 (authorization code flow - PKCE) in a project using Vue.js and ASP.NET Core Web Api. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try look here: https://github.com/damienbod/IdentityServer4VueJs

Comment: Also check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55210705/how-to-protect-asp-net-core-2-1-and-vue-js-single-page-application-with-identity?answertab=active#tab-top